# How to export WordPress comments with post informations

Tags: wordpress, csv, comments, export-to-csv, posts

I need to export all the comments on a WordPress website but I also need to have the post title of the currrent comments being exported.

Surprisingly none of the popular WP plugins seems to offer this possiblity. How would you do that?

I was thinking working with 2 sheets in Excel as I am capable to export the comments in one CSV and my posts in an another, but it seems really complicated for my current need.

I was hoping exporting one CSV file only in which I would have automatically the comment's informations but also the related post's informations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export Wordpress comments with post informations in PhpMyAdmin.

This simple Query will be a good starting point:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_comments.comment_ID, wp_comments.comment_post_ID,
  wp_comments.comment_author, wp_comments.comment_author_email, 
  wp_comments.comment_author_url,
  wp_comments.comment_author_IP,wp_comments.comment_date, 
  wp_comments.comment_content, wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title 

FROM `wp_comments` INNER JOIN `wp_posts` 

WHERE wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
```

Up to you then to select the columns you want to export.

Comment: Amazing, that did the job, I just need to cleanup some columns but, yay.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm adding a question here, as the query your advise me to use is strangely exporting comments in a duplicate way for different post_type, is there a way to export only the post's comments without any duplicate entries? 

Tried many things this morning with DISTINCT and advanced way to export my tables data and it's still not working.

Thanks.

Comment: I updated my example query for my records and the community 

Comment: Thanks Gael, it is exactly what I needed. I see what I did wrong now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Great work Gael! Thank you for sharing it with the communiity. I've just used the code now and it worked.

Had to do some trial and error to export properly, due to the accents (UTF8 did not work properly). And in the excel deleted all rows where the comment_author was Woocommerce or a Administrator user, since it were all technical automatic comments (didn't knew these were stored at this table to)